# getting error on while inserting a single quotation values

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb6

Table1

```
EmpName1 

Raja
Rav'i
Ramu'i
Rajes'ih
```

Table2

```
EmpName2

....
```

When I inserting table2.empname2 from table1.empname1, It inserted only the raja, remaining rows were not inserted it showing error in '(single quotation)

```
"Showing error as incorrect syntax near rav"
```

vb6 code.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (EmpName) VALUES('" & EmpName & "')
```

How can I insert a name with a single quotation also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either escape your single quotation with something like

```
empName = replace(empName, "'", "''")
```

or paramertize your query...

Comment: To make it more clear, you'll want to replace the single quotes with two single quotes.  The SQL Server will convert those into a single single quote.

Answer (score 2):

It is highly recommended to use a parametrized query (see e.g. [this article](http://www.asp.net/Learn/data-access/tutorial-48-vb.aspx)), instead of building your SQL query as a string. This protects you from many forms of SQL injection, and is also often faster.

Or directly use some kind of persistence framework, if you have a lot of DB interaction.

Your query will not work because in string SQL queries, the ' must be escaped (as ''). And BTW, if you want to insert values from one table into another, it is usually not a good idea to do a SELECT, then an INSERT in a loop, like you do. Just do a

> INSERT INTO table2 SELECT ... FROM table1

Comment: He is asking a VB6 question.  The link points to a vb.net tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; I've never worked with either, sorry. Anyway, parametrized queries are a concept independent of any particular language, so it should not matter :-).